# Ionic customize color of ionic refresher spinner icon

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3, spinner

How can I customize the the styles of ionic refresher spinner icon for every page? In each page on my app the spinner should have different color depending where page the user is on. I have done something like this in my css. But I only customized the background color of the refresher to gray.

Here is the **styles.css**

```
ion-refresher * {
    // background-color: white;
    ion-refresher-content * {
      icon * {
        color: #dd2727;
      }
      color: red;
        .refresher-refreshing {
          .refresher-pulling-icon, .refresher-refreshing-icon {
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-transform-origin: center;
            transform-origin: center;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #dd2727;
            -webkit-transition: 200ms;
            transition: 200ms;
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Here is the **page.html**

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
      <ion-refresher-content
        pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
        refreshingSpinner="crescent">
      </ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>
```

I tried googling for it but can't find any solutions.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check refresher component on ionic documentation 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

They have specified sass variables in the bottom to change styling as per our needs:

```
$refresher-icon-color
$refresher-icon-font-size
$refresher-text-color
$refresher-text-font-size
$refresher-border-color
```

So say you want to use `$refresher-icon-color: red;`  in your app you can call this variable in `theme/variable.scss` which will override the default styles.

Css

Circle svg

```
.refresher-refreshing .spinner-crescent circle, .refresher-refreshing .spinner-ios line, .refresher-refreshing .spinner-ios-small line{
   stroke : red;
}
```

Pulling icon css

```
.refresher-pulling-icon, .refresher-refreshing-icon{
  color: red
}
```

Every page in ionic has the page-name format so you can add your working styles in individual page scss file and if you want to change color of spinner icon then its an svg you can use above css in page scss file itself.

Like this:

```
page-spinner{
    .refresher-refreshing .spinner-crescent circle, .refresher-refreshing .spinner-ios line, .refresher-refreshing .spinner-ios-small line{
       stroke : red;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have a different color of refresher spinners from every page. I would want to do it on my own but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you this helped me alot. I can also customize the pulling icon right? Btw where did you get those classes and how did you figure it out? Inspect element?

Comment: Yeah some component in ionic is basically set to display:none if its inactive so you can actually inspect and set it to block or remove display: none and play with it.

Comment: I learned so alot from you. Thank you for this. Big thumbs up.

Comment: Hi there @Ajaj Rajguru can I ask your help about refresher again? But a new problem or issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174920/discussion-between-ajaj-rajguru-and-knowledgeseeker).

Comment: Hi Ajaj Rajguru, I am having a problem with ion refresher too. I am wondering if you know how to change the pulling icon and refresh icon to another icon or gif?

Comment: Interesting but, what about Ionic 4?

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 4 I managed to change the pulling icon (default a dark arrow) using

```
ion-refresher ion-refresher-content .refresher-pulling .refresher-pulling-icon ion-icon {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```